# Stuck scrolling of a list, using Sencha Touch

Tags: list, extjs, sencha-touch

What I am trying to do is have a "load more" button at the bottom of a ajax populated list. I have got all the code working with a docked button, but I would now like to have it at the bottom.

What is happening is when the `listView` card is show I see my list but the list won't scroll. It pulls up and down a little but just won't have it. I have tried adding different configurations and layouts to `listView` with no different.

What I have done is the following

```
var moreButton = new Ext.Button({
    text: 'Load more...',
    ui: 'round',
    handler: function() {//Do the loading - this works}
});

//In my list config I have a docked top bar for going "back" other than that pretty standard
var list = new Ext.List(Ext.apply(listConfig, {
    fullscreen: false
}));

//This is my view for what I am trying to do
var listView = new Ext.Container({
    items:[list, moreButton]
});
```

`listView` is then added to an other container as it is populated from a search box, it is show with `setCard` when I get a valid response from the server.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a way to do this? I'm stuck on the same problem.

Answer (score 0):

[sencha person] are you on 0.98? I think we had a regression in our scroller. Might want to downgrade back to 0.97